# Configuring Vert.x HTTPS server to work with react-native mobile client

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, react-native, vert.x

I have configured my Vert.x server built in Java to already handle HTTP connections properly, but I would like to add an additional layer of security through HTTPS. I use the standard fetch call to make POST requests to the server. I have searched through the Vert.x documentation already, but the only information I can find is if I use Vert.x as client code as well, but I would like to avoid that if possible. Is there a way to configure my client and server to work together to form a secure connection without having to build an encryption schema from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have but one VertX instance, without load balancer, and you would like to access it using HTTPS protocol.
It doesn't actually matter whether you access it through

When starting your VertX server, make sure you specify `setSSL(true)` and all the other arguments:
https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-examples/blob/master/src/raw/java/https/ServerExample.java#L39